# How to remove popup while login using facebook oauth in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

Currently I am using **WebBrowser Control** for open  facebook login page. When I login using facebook in my wpf application then a popup appears and it shows "Stop running this script" like this. I am attaching this screenshot.This wll provide you more information: http://screencast.com/t/FS39IN4dbXI, This message comes again and again.

So can you please help me how to remove this type of popup?

Answer (score 0):

//with code:

webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed     = true;

//on properties:

WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false ---
ScriptErrorsSuppressed     = true

Comment: I have added these lines.After adding these lines it gives "Navigation to webpage was cancelled". i have simply add these lines         browser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
browser.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com");

Comment: you can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422725/webbrowser-control-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled

Comment: This is not working.It gives same error which I have recieved previously like this "Stop running this script"