# Webbrowser navigation canceled even if the file exists

Tags: c#, .net

I already browse this question but it was not very useful: [WebBrowser control page load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223245/webbrowser-control-page-load-error) (or maybe I didn't catch the thing)

I use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display the content of a PDF in my application (C# .NET 4.5). I try to navigate into the local URL of the file (which I can open with the explorer) with this code:

```
m_path = pdfDoc.CreateReportFile();
try
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(m_path));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}
```

But the navigation is always canceled, even if I try to reload the page. No exception is thrown.

What can I do?

Here's the URL: `C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\LY20_2014-11-25_06#22M1[1].pdf`

If I paste it in IE, remove the escaping `\`, the file does open.

## Update:

- The webbrowser works fine when entering the string `@"http://www.google.fr"`
- When using the PDF file address it opens it in Acrobat Reader after the *Navigation Canceled* message

Comment: You do know that catching and rethrowing like that is of no use, don't you? Can you post the complete url?

Comment: Did you try opening an existing PDF with the same code?

Comment: @MartinDelille you mean replacing m_path with the PDF file?

Comment: no. Test your code without calling pdfDoc.CreateReportFile() and assign to *m_path* a valid PDF file path.

Comment: Beware of double backslashes. Those should NOT be part of the string. Double backslashes are ONLY needed when you are typing a literal string in your code in order to escape the backslash and you are not using `@` before the quotes. Make sure your string is actually `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\LY20_2014-11-25_06#22M1[1].pdf`.

Comment: @MartinDelille it doesn't work either with a valid path :(

Comment: @Andrew the path is provided using `Path.GetTempPath()` so I assume the double backslashes are not an issue, furthermore when I right-click => Address the webbrowser, the right address is displayed

Comment: When you create the pdfDoc is it in read only mode or are freeing it to be use by any application ?

Comment: @MaximeMangel I'm pretty sure it's not read only but I'll check again. I just updated the post

Comment: @Thomas Then I'll suggest you to remove the line concerning pdfDoc if you think it is not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dear Adobe and Microsoft, [we can't display a 32bits ActiveX in a 64bits WebBrowser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2935492/en-us) at least, they are honest :

> Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products that are listed in the "Applies to" section.